# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' while using re.match for renaming of file names

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to rename some files which all start with the same string (Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_) in a folder using pyhton on windows.

An example file-name: 
Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_004_Term Sheet.docx

New file-name should look like this: 4.docx

My current code looks like this:

```
import os
import re

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    m = re.match("Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_(\d+)_(\w+(\W\w+)*)\.docx", filename)    
    number = m.group(1)  
    new_filename = number + ".docx"
    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
    print(new_filename)
```

I'm getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:(...)rename.py", line 6, in 
    number = m.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I checked the regex with several filenames here: https://regex101.com/ and it was always a perfect match.

I'm new to python and before asking the question I searched a long time and all the tips about normalizing the file name didn't help.

I changed the script after input from blurp to:

```
import os
import re

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    m = re.match(r'Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_(\d+)_(\w+(\W\w+)*)\.docx', filename)    
    number = m.group(1)  
    new_filename = number + ".docx"
    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
    print(new_filename)
```

Still the same error and still a match when I check the regex.

To test the regex match I used now:

```
import os
import re

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    m = re.match(r'Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_(\d+)_(\w+(\W\w+)*)\.docx', filename)  
    number = m.group(1)  
    new_filename = number + ".docx"
    if m is not None:
        os.rename(filename, new_filename)
        print(new_filename)
```

Still same error message.

Okay, as a last resort I tried this in a folder which contained only the file Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_003_Letter.docx:

```
import os, sys
import re

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    m = re.match(r"Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_(\d+)_(\w+(\W\w+)*)\.docx", filename)    
    print(m)
```

I got the following result:
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 40), match='Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_003_Letter.docx'>

Looks like it is matching, still the error.

Comment: `re.match()` returns `None` when your regex doesn't match. You can check for that by doing `if m is not None`. Also, you need to prefix the regex pattern with `r` like `r"xyz"`, otherwise things like `\d` won't work. See the [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) for more about that.

Comment: I copied your regex (the `r''` version) and sample file name into a little script and it worked for me. Do all the files in the directory match the pattern? If not, you'll have to check for `None`.

Comment: I'm trying to insert the None test as well but I will always get invalid syntax. I tried:

Comment: `if m is not None
        os.rename(filename, new_filename)
        print(new_filename)`

Comment: There seems to be a colon missing after `None`.

Comment: Right at the moment I'm testing in an extra folder using just the one file which I have posted above...

Comment: Is your Python script in that folder?

Comment: Yes the Python script is in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `re.match()` if the string supplied doesn't match the regex pattern, it will equal `None`.

What I'm assuming the problem is, is that you are coming across a filename that doesn't match the regex pattern you have supplied.

Even if the regex matches your files correctly, the first time `re.match()` returns `None` it will break unless you explicitly catch it. Otherwise, when you call `re.match().group()`, it doesn't exist and it raises an error.

This worked for me when I made files with the name format specified:

```
import os
import re

def rename_num(path):

    # Create a pattern to match filenames to
    match_pattern = r"Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_(\d+)_(\w+(\W\w+)*)\.docx"
    pattern = re.compile(match_pattern)


    # For each file in the path supplied above
    for filename in os.listdir(path):

        # Use the re module to match the regex pattern to the filename.
        # If the filename doesn't match the regex found will be equal to None.
        found = pattern.match(filename)

        # If found is not equal to None, print the filename, groups and rename the file
        if found:

            os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, found.group(1) + ".docx"))

            print("{} renamed to {}".format(filename, found.group(1) + ".docx"))



# To run the above method in the directory the script is in:
p = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
rename_num(p)
```

> #### I created files with names like you supplied (numbers 001 - 007) and
>
> #### this was my output:
>
> ```
> Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_001_Term Sheet.docx renamed to 001.docx
> Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_002_Term Sheet.docx renamed to 002.docx
> Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_003_Term Sheet.docx renamed to 003.docx
> Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_004_Term Sheet.docx renamed to 004.docx
> Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_005_Term Sheet.docx renamed to 005.docx
> Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_006_Term Sheet.docx renamed to 006.docx
> Vertragshandbuch_Beitrag_007_Term Sheet.docx renamed to 007.docx
> ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much Jebby. That worked now first in the test folder with the single file where it didn't work before, than also in the whole folder after a few more changes to regex to get also names with '-' in it. It must have been the re.compile which did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you, please accept it as the solution.

Comment: @rena `re.compile()` doesn’t have any effect on whether a pattern will match.

Comment: This is correct. `re.compile()` just has speed improvements over `re.match()` so it is preferred when matching that pattern with multiple strings at a time. (Like in a for loop). Should have mentioned that. Thanks @Blurp

Comment: Also, note that when using functions like `re.match()` and `re.search()`, the patterns will be automatically compiled and cached ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)).

Comment: Thanks for further explanation. But in this case I don't understand, why it worked with Jebby's script and with mine not. I tested as mentioned with **a folder which contained just 1 file**. **The file name was obviously a match, because  I didn't change the regex in Jebby's script.** It worked with his script but not with mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer, you can also make your matches optional. This way, you will get a match object (not `None`), even if your string does not match.

> Putting this on top, because it's very important: `.*` and similar
>   will run over optional matches, so this will not work if you don't
>   know what might be surrounding the substring you'd like to capture.

That being said, here's the usual behavior.

```
>>> re.match('(a)', a).groups()
('a',)

>>> re.match('(a)', b).groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

A `?` after the parenthesis makes the match for 'a' optional.

```
>>> re.match('(a)?', 'a').groups()
('a',)

>>> re.match('(a)?', 'b').groups()
(None,)
```

You can even pass a default value to `groups`.

```
re.match('(a)?', 'a').groups('cannot find a')
('a',)

re.match('(a)?', 'b').groups('cannot find a')
('cannot find a',)
```

This can sometimes make for more readable code.